# What is the Aghora Mantra mentioned in Shiva Mahimna Stotram Verse 35?

Tags: shiva, mantras, shiva-mahimna-stotra

Shiva Mahimna Stotram Verse 35

> महेशान्नापरो देवो महिम्नो नापरा स्तुतिः। 
> **अघोरान्नापरो मन्त्रो** नास्ति तत्त्वं गुरोः परम्॥
>
> Maheśānnāparo devo mahimno nāparā stutiḥ| 
> **Aghorānnāparo mantro** nāsti tattvaṁ guroḥ param||

*There is no God greater than Lord Mahesha,
No Stuti greater than Mahimna,
No Mantra greater than the **Aghora**,
And no Tatwa greater than the Guru.*

Which Mantra exactly is mentioned here?

Comment: It must be referring to Rudra Prashna (Sri Rudram) of which the Rishi is Aghora. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20671

Comment: Its possibly ॐ अघोरेभ्योऽथ घोरेभ्यो घोर घोर तरेभ्यः
सर्वेभ्यस् सर्व सर्वेभ्यो नमस्तेऽस्तु रुद्र रूपेभ्यः

Comment: Its recited while wearing Rudraksha

Comment: @Rickross While I understand the reason behind your thinking but I don't think it is referring to Sri Rudram.  If it was referring Sri Rudram, then definitely mentioned the word 'Rudram' and a Mantra unlikely to be named after the Rishi, like we rarely call Gayatri Mantra as Viswamitra Mantra or Mahamrityunjaya Mantra as Markandeya Mantra.  Mantra generally named after the Deity.

Comment: @Rickross Just to add, Mantra also named based on how many syllables in the Mantra.  I have never heard Sri Rudram mentioned by the name of Aghora Mantra, and I believe here the Rishi Aghora is not Aghora form of Lord Shiva but referring to Kanva Rishi.  So I am confused.

Comment: @Proxy Yes, I see this as a possibility

Answer (score 1):

Not a very direct confirmation but Yes its: (in link (2) its mentioned in *Rudraksha Dhahran vidhi*.)

> ॐ अघोरेभ्योऽथ घोरेभ्यो घोर घोर तरेभ्यः सर्वेभ्यस् सर्व सर्वेभ्यो नमस्तेऽस्तु रुद्र रूपेभ्यः

See [1](http://www.aghori.it/aghori_mantra.htm), [2](https://archive.org/details/rudrakshabhasmaaurtripundravigyanrandhirprakashan/page/n43/mode/2up), [3](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_shiva/aghoramUrtikavacham.html)

Answer (score 1):

Mantra-s are beings, who are residing in the higher plane of existence that is being governed by Aghora form of param Śiva is the reason Aghora has been called the highest mantra, i.e. the highest being residing in that particular plane of existence.

> The word ‘hṛdaya’ is synonymous with consciousness.  Śiva`s form which is of the nature of that consciousness is  pure and tranquil. Being free from the state  of  dreadfulness (aghora), the mantra assumes the form ‘aghora hṛdaya’... - Mṛgendra Āgama 3.11.