# Shakta mantras that do not need initiation

Tags: vedas, mantras, shakti, shaktism, initiation

Is there any mantra like om namha shivaya or om namo bhagvate vasudevaye for shakta that can be chanted without initiation?

Comment: The corresponding Shakti mantra will be Om hrim klim chamundaye vicche but it requires initiation like all other mantras .. also how do you know that the two mantras you mentioned can be chanted without initiation?

Comment: @Rickross It's a naam japa right, I mean these mantras doesn't include any bija mantra

Comment: Not nama japa .. namah shivaya is the panchakshari mantra found in the Vedas .. so it's a Vedic mantra @AbhinavRaj

Comment: See the following posts -- (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17498/4732), (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/20613/4732) @AbhinavRaj

Comment: @Rickross isn't it *om **aim** hreem kleem chamundaye vicchaye* ?

Comment: Yes om aim .. didn't realize that I missed aim @Rāmachandra